# Return a list without using NHibernate object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, ef-code-first

Suppose I have an interface.

```
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    IList<Blog> Blogs(int pageNo, int pageSize);
    int TotalPosts();
}
```

Now I created a class to implement it and use NHibernate.

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Criterion;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using NHibernate.Transform;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace JustBlog.Core
{
    public class BlogRepository: IBlogRepository
    {
        // NHibernate object
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public BlogRepository(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public IList<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
        {
            var query = _session.Query<Post>()
                        .Where(p => p.Published)
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
                        .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .Fetch(p => p.Category);

            query.FetchMany(p => p.Tags).ToFuture();

            return query.ToFuture().ToList();
        }

        public int TotalPosts()
        {
            return _session.Query<Post>().Where(p => p.Published).Count();
        }
    }
```

The above code is from somewhere on the web [for creating a blog engine](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1#book-unique-identifier). However I don't know NHibernate at all, I use Entity Framework to do my job.

How can I rewrite the code without using NHiberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Entity Models**

Assuming we have our entity models like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public Post() { Tags = new List<Tag>(); }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public string Meta{ get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug{ get; set; }
    public bool Published{ get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified{ get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

Our context class is pretty simple. The constructor takes in the name of the connection string in `web.config` and we define three `DbSet`s:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext() : base("BlogContextConnectionStringName") { }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

The interface for our blog repository is nice and easy and doesn't change much:

```
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize);
    int TotalPosts();
}
```

And it's the blog repository itself where things get interesting!

```
public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
{
    // NHibernate object replace with our context
    private readonly BlogContext _blogContext;

    public BlogRepository(BlogContext blogContext)
    {
        _blogContext = blogContext;
    }

    //Function to get a list of blogs
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
    {
        //We start with the blogs db set:
        var query = _blogContext.Posts
            //Filter by Published=true
            .Where(p => p.Published)
            //Order by date they were posted
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
            //Jump through the list
            .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
            //Get the required number of blogs
            .Take(pageSize)
            //Make sure the query include all the categories
            .Include(b => b.Category);

        //Just return what we have!
        return query;
    }

    //Much simpler function, should be pretty self explanatory
    public int TotalPosts()
    {
        return _blogContext.Posts.Where(p => p.Published).Count();
    }
}
```

**Next Steps**

OK, so now we have all that set up, and a nice connection string is set up in your web.config, what do we do with it? Well let's get some blogs!

```
var context = new BlogContext();
var repository = new BlogRepository(context);
var posts = repository.Posts(0, 10);
```

Then we can do some stuff with those blogs:

```
foreach(var blog in blogs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Blog Id {0} was posted on {1} and has {2} categories", blog.Id, blog.PostedOn, blog.Categories.Count());
}
```

**Notes**

I didn't implement the `FetchMany/ToFuture` parts as they're not needed here.

Comment: --@DavidG,Why did you apply ICollection to Category? Original link doesn't have it. I got an error at the code `Include`..

Comment: OK, good question. First of all I didn't copy the models from the website you mentioned, I just made up my own. Would you like me to rewrite it with those in mind? And what is the error you get with `Include`?

Comment: --@DavidG, ignore the error, I missed a reference. Now it is okay. Yes, I would like the original models with the link so I can follow the rest walkthrough. Thanks.

Comment: @Love OK, I've made the changes. Let me know if you need any more :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use Linq to Entities mapping your model from the DB.

First of all, create in your database the tables exactly as the objects defined in the post you link, remember to add the relationships.

Then add an ADO Entity data model and populate it from your database selecting those tables, you will end with an XXXEntities which is an ObjectContext with all the classes already created.

Finally, doing the query will be something like this (supose your Entities are named BlogEntities):

```
public IEnumerable<Blog> Posts(int pageNo, int pageSize)
{

    using(BlogEntities con = new BlogEntities())
    {

        var query = con.Post.Include("Category") //<-- If you set "Pluralize fields and properties" when creating your model, it will be "Posts" and "Categories"
                    .Where(p => p.Published)
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostedOn)
                    .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToList();

        return query;

    }

}

public int TotalPosts()
{
    using(BlogEntities con = new BlogEntities())
    {

          return con.Post.Where(p => p.Published).Count();

    }

}
```